# Dynamics crmservice asmx and caching

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a custom app which uses the crmservice.asmx to retrieve contacts from dynamics crm 4.

The problem: I search for the contact in my custom app and don't find it. I go to MSCRM and create the contact. When I then try to search again in my custom app, I still can't find the contact.

It has to be cache for the crmservice.asmx because when I try 10 minutes later, the contact is found in my custom app.

But how do I manage the cache settings on the crmservice.asmx?

My code for instantiating

```
Private Const CRMServiceUrl As String = "https://*****/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx"
Private Const MetadataServiceUrl As String = "https://*****/MSCRMServices/2007/MetadataService.asmx"
Private Const OrganizationName As String = "****"
Private Const Username As String = "****"
Private Const Password As String = "****"
Private Const Domain As String = "****"

Private ReadOnly _service As CrmService.CrmService
Private ReadOnly _metadataService As MetadataService.MetadataService


Public Sub New()
    Dim crmServiceToken As New CrmAuthenticationToken()
    crmServiceToken.AuthenticationType = Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.AuthenticationType.AD
    crmServiceToken.OrganizationName = OrganizationName

    Dim metadataServiceToken As New MetadataService.CrmAuthenticationToken()
    metadataServiceToken.AuthenticationType = Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.AuthenticationType.AD
    metadataServiceToken.OrganizationName = OrganizationName

    Dim credentials As ICredentials = New NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain)

    _service = New CrmService.CrmService()
    _service.Url = CRMServiceUrl
    _service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = crmServiceToken
    _service.Credentials = credentials

    _metadataService = New MetadataService.MetadataService()
    _metadataService.Url = MetadataServiceUrl
    _metadataService.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = metadataServiceToken
    _metadataService.Credentials = credentials
End Sub
```

and the method that gets contacts

```
Public Function GetContact(ByVal request As GetContactRequest) As contact Implements ICRM.GetContact
    Dim query As New QueryExpression()
    query.EntityName = EntityName.contact.ToString()
    query.ColumnSet = New AllColumns()

    Dim condition As ConditionExpression
    Dim expr As New List(Of ConditionExpression)

    condition = New ConditionExpression()
    condition.AttributeName = "statecode"
    condition.[Operator] = ConditionOperator.Equal
    condition.Values = New Object() {0}
    expr.Add(condition)

    If request.ContactId <> Guid.Empty Then
        condition = New ConditionExpression()
        condition.AttributeName = "contactid"
        condition.[Operator] = ConditionOperator.Equal
        condition.Values = New String() {request.ContactId.ToString}
        expr.Add(condition)
    End If
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.CustomerCode) Then
        condition = New ConditionExpression()
        condition.AttributeName = "new_orgcustomerno"
        condition.[Operator] = ConditionOperator.Like
        condition.Values = New String() {request.CustomerCode + "%"}
        expr.Add(condition)
    End If

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ContactSeq) Then
        condition = New ConditionExpression()
        condition.AttributeName = "new_contact_seq"
        condition.[Operator] = ConditionOperator.Like
        condition.Values = New String() {request.ContactSeq + "%"}
        expr.Add(condition)
    End If


    Dim filter As New FilterExpression()
    filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.[And]
    filter.Conditions = expr.ToArray

    query.Criteria = filter
    Dim contacts As BusinessEntityCollection = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query)

    If contacts.BusinessEntities.Length > 0 Then
        Dim a As contact = DirectCast(contacts.BusinessEntities(0), contact)
        Return a
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see you code. This doesn't sound to me like expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: by using Retrieve() instead of RetrieveMultiple() I get the contact at once.

this means that by searching for the newly created contact by other columns, I can't access it at once (have to wait a couple of minutes). I have to use the contactid.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a suggestion, but I don't think that it's related somehow with the caching. Possible issues are either permissions issue or conditions issue. I mean, if you have created contact when you was logged in CRM as some user, but trying to retrieve previously created contact under other CRM user. Or might be additional columns you have added to conditions list, might some from them has not that value you suppose to be there.

Comment: Is the user executing the call to CRM the same user as the one who created the contact? It not, can you try making that call as a test. Does this problem exist if you only set contactid and leave ContactSeq Null or empty? I'm wondering if it could have something to do with indexing the like comparison operator on that field.

Comment: thanks @ThinkPlusPlus i will check this out at the end of the day, and try to fetch the contact with exact values and without the like comparison.